# NullPointerException at OpenShift cloud

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is my java code:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Gson gson = new Gson();

Session session = null;
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List currencies = session.createQuery("from Currency").list();
    response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(currencies));
    tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

I don't get any errors, when I run this code at my computer. But I receive NullPointerException when I run it at OpenShift cloud. Exception at line session.close();

My cartridges in OpenShift are Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0), MySQL 5.5, phpMyAdmin 4.0.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/program </property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">login</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="com.gmail.user.persistence/Currency.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I need an advice how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Post the stack trace.  Better yet, attach to the instance and step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove "**session.close();**" from your "**finally**" block.Because the session was already closed, so when compiler try to run the finally block it getting null pointer exception,

Comment: if session is already closed then you will get exception as `Session was already closed`, not the NullPointerException. To check if session is not yet closed we can use `session.isOpen()` method

Comment: I've removed `session.close()` after this an error about mysql port appeared. I changed in hibernate.cfg.xml connection url from `jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/program` to `jdbc:mysql://127.7.242.2:3306/program` and now I don't get any error. I got IP and port from the phpMyAdmin. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't eat exception! Change your code to:

```
catch (HibernateException e) {
   LOG.warn("",e);
   if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
}
```

then you will know why session is null.